# I am getting a CORS error when redirecting to an external URL from my server

Tags: redirect, cors, svelte, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit to run a server on localhost:5173. On the front end, when a button is clicked it calls the `/login` endpoint of my server. That endpoint builds the query params and redirects to the Spotify /Authorize end points, [as outlined in their docs.](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow#Request%20User%20Authorization).

My `/login` endpoint looks like this (client ID ommitted):

```
export function GET(url){
    let params = new URLSearchParams({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: '...',
        scope: 'playlist-modify-private playlist-read-private',
        redirect_uri: `localhost:5173`
    });

    let endpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?';
    throw new redirect(308, endpoint + params.toString())
}
```

The response I get when is the following:
`Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&scope=playlist-modify-private+playlist-read-private&redirect_uri=localhost%3A5173' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5173/login') from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I am assuming I need to setup the proper CORS access origin, but I am not sure where to do that in SveletKit, specifically when throwing redirects as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, CORS happens when your app is trying to request a domain that you haven't specified that it should be permitted to get resources from there.

A quick "fix" to this would just install the `cors` package:

```
npm i cors
```

Then add it to your express app as such:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

However, it would be more secure if you specified what domains exactly you want to bypass CORS, like this:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: // List of domains
}));
```

Here's a great link that provides more insight into this matter: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/